# Message method of Gmail Api gets messages from which label

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to display message id's from Gmail and its count...As all specifies that ALL Mail contains mails from all the labels, But in output it displays count as 667 and actually in my mail box All Mail have 405 mails only.. I am not understanding that what exactly get printed on output window in my case. I would like to know about the method Message of Gmail API returns list of messages from which label.
Please help me.
Thank you

```
public static List<Message> ListMessages(GmailService service, String userId, String query)
{
    List<Message> result = new List<Message>();
    List<Label> Labels = new List<Label>();        
    UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
    UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request1 = service.Users.Labels.List(userId);
    request.Q = query;
    int i = 0;       
    ListLabelsResponse response1 = request1.Execute();

    Console.WriteLine("\n \nList of labels with id's: ");
    foreach (Label label in response1.Labels)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(label.Id + " - " + label.Name);
    }

    do
    {
        try
        {
            ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
            result.AddRange(response.Messages);
            request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
            //Console.WriteLine("\n List of messages Id's: ", result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }
    } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

    (...)
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are also seeing trashed or spam emails that rnt in your inbox

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the API documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/

You can download a list of user's labels using [gmail.users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.labels.list)

Then you can get the number of emails in specific labels using [gmail.users.labels.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.labels.get)

On this documnetation website you can add authorize your gmail account and test all the API methods in the broweser - it's really convenient to debug all results.